# SQL query to Relational Algebra, how to join the same tables?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

In relational algebra, how do you join a table onto itself?

The question:

branch (**branch_name**, branch_city, assets)

account (**account_number**, branch_name, balance)

Now, consider the following SQL query:

```
Select T.branch_name  
From branch T, branch S  
Where T.assets > S.assets and S.branch_city = “Shanghai”
```

Write the most optimized relational-algebra expression that is equivalent to that query. Justify your choice.

I'm a bit confused. I know how to join two tables together, say branch to account, but I am not sure how to join two of the same tables together under these circumstances.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Your query is _already_ doing a self join, double check your syntax.

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give a reference and/or definition for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. Define "translate"/"convert"--Same result? Same structure? How does an SQL table correspond to a relation--what if a table has duplicate rows or nulls? Define "most optimized". PS Show what parts you can do & what you have tried. Explain "under these circumstances". See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

You would join two tables together like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
branch INNER JOIN account ON (branch.X=account.Y)
WHERE ...
```

To do a self join you would do the same thing, except alias one (or both) of the tables so it's more clear:

```
SELECT * FROM
branch AS branch1 JOIN branch AS branch2 ON (branch1.X=branch2.Y)
WHERE ...
```

Additionally, you can put the `WHERE` clause in the join condition itself:

```
SELECT * FROM
branch AS branch1 JOIN branch AS branch2 ON (branch1.X=branch2.Y AND branch1.A > branch2.B)
```

Sorry if the above is a bit vague and doesn't use your exact variable names -- I'm a bit confused on the example you've given above, so if you want to update your question or leave a comment I can update the examples.

Comment: _If_ this question is asking for relational algebra, then an answer in SQL isn't right. But the q doesn't specify which version of RA. As to "most optimized", any of your answers might be that, or they might all be equal -- it depends entirely on the execution engine/query plan, not the specific syntax of SQL.